# Python script for reading messages on Facebook

Tags: python, facebook

I want to write a python script that can detect new messages on Facebook messenger and store what the message says as a variable that I could use for other things.  how could I do something like that, and would it work with multiple messages from the same person? maybe adding the contents of multiple messages into the same group of text and then storing them as a variable. idk, I'm fairly new to python lol. thanks in advance

I haven't tried yet, but I am about to :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a _specific_ programming problem. Please read [ask].

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Sorry about that, it's my first time using the site. ill try the code and come back with more specific problems, thank you.